# Service Fabric Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade - How to make powershell wait for successful upgrade before continuing

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I am converting away from using the Azure devops pipeline "Upgrade Service Fabric Application" task and replacing it with a pure PowerShell approach.

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/$(ServiceFabricApplicationName) -ApplicationTypeVersion $BuildNumber -ApplicationParameter $settings -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
```

The issue is that when I use the devops pipeline task, it waits for the upgrade to complete and shows output in the console window. When I use my custom powershell, it executes immediately and moved to the next pipeline task even though in my cluster I can see the upgrade just got started. How can I make it show output and wait for success before it moves on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command [Get-Service Fabric Application Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/get-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps) will get the status of a Service Fabric application upgrade, so we can use it in the following PowerShell script to get the result of this upgradation.

```
## Start monitored application upgrade
try
{
    Write-Host "Start upgrading application..." 
    Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/$(ServiceFabricApplicationName) -ApplicationTypeVersion $BuildNumber -ApplicationParameter $settings -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
}
catch
{
    Write-Host ("Error starting upgrade. " + $_)

    Write-Host "Unregister application..."
    Unregister-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationTypeName fabric:/$(ServiceFabricApplicationName) -ApplicationTypeVersion $BuildNumber -Force
    throw
}

do
{
    Write-Host "Waiting for upgrade..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
    $upgradeStatus = Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/$(ServiceFabricApplicationName)
} while ($upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -ne "RollingBackCompleted" -and $upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -ne "RollingForwardCompleted" -and $upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -ne "Failed")
    
if($upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -eq "RollingForwardCompleted")
{
    Write-Host "Upgrade completed successfully."
}
elseif($upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -eq "RollingBackCompleted")
{
    Write-Error "Upgrade was Rolled back."
}
elseif($upgradeStatus.UpgradeState -eq "Failed")
{
    Write-Error "Upgrade Failed."
}
```

Therefore, this PowerShell task will wait for the result of this upgradation before it moves to the next pipeline task.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below, it will wait for the scriptblock to complete and run the next lines.

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/$(ServiceFabricApplicationName) -ApplicationTypeVersion $BuildNumber -ApplicationParameter $settings -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback
} 
Wait-Job $job.Name
```